# `include` (and `input`) with part of a file name

Tags: formatting, include

Is it possible to use the `\include` and `\input` commands with only part of a file name and use relative directories? I.e.

```
\include{Part1}
\include{Part2}
```

instead of

```
\include{Part1_Filename}
\include{Part2_Filename}
```

I often have very long file names to better be able to identify my documents and in cases where I write chapters (or sections) in each their .tex-file, then with many chapters it would be easy and simple, if one could just type a part of the file name. 
Hence, is it possible to refer to a file with only part of its name with the  `\include` command?

Comment: Hi and welcome, i don't think so. You can omit the file ending in most cases, but the `basename` should be given in full and it needs to be unique. A relative (or even absolute) path is optional.

Comment: In `\include` you ***must*** skip the extension! But TeX uses the normal filesystem utilities for finding files and with them you can't just give a part of the name. In the shell you can TAB for completion, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: How unfortunate. Thanks for explaining and thanks for expanding on the extension, @egreg - I did not know that, I just always excluded it.

Comment: Is this really a big deal? I mean, looking at your case, it’s not something you would do often. Even if you have many parts, the “wasted” time would be infinitesimal compared to the writing time. Beside, it seems possible with Lua(La)TeX.

Comment: @HarishKumar Why? The answer is just two letters: NO. Or “execute a complicated script that tries file completion, with all security issues that arise”.

Comment: I tried to clarify what I meant back when I posted the question. I now understand my idea with easy referencing could easily be solved with a proper directory structure instead of using complicated file names.